# how to fetch date from list of data in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of json coming from api in which date is present as shown below. How can i extract this date. I have just shown random data that is data number may be 1 or 2 or 3 digits. Here in this case we have data number 24,124,04. Date is in yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
data-24-1296176045661093905-33-2021-03-10T12-22-47.26942346.json
data-124-1296176045661093905-33-2021-05-14T12-22-47.26942346.json
data-04-1296176045661093905-33-2021-09-19T12-22-47.26942346.json
```

Since this list is dynamic, so data number may change. How can i get date from it???

Comment: What is "data-24-1296176045661093905-33-2021-03-10T12-22-47.26942346.json" ? It is a filename or just a date stamp? how this date is calculated?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara it is a file name. I have to fetch data present in the file name so that i can apply sorting (based on latest data by date)

Comment: My question is the file name must be created with some format? Do all the files follow the same same structure? like - day is always concatenated with "10T12" ?

Comment: yes... All file follows the same structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of this right now. This will work well for the stated filenames:

```js
const arr = ['data-24-1296176045661093905-33-2021-03-10T12-22-47.26942346.json',
'data-124-1296176045661093905-33-2021-05-14T12-22-47.26942346.json',
'data-04-1296176045661093905-33-2021-09-19T12-22-47.26942346.json']
const getDate = (fileName) => {
    return fileName.split(/(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\T)/)[1].split('-').slice(3).join('-');
}

arr.forEach(fileName => console.log(getDate(fileName)));
```